# Displaying an ajax spinner on each of the multiple checkboxes with rails and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a large form with multiple checkboxes in Rails 4.2 app.

I am not quite sure what's the best way to implement loading a spinner on the clicked checkbox when it is clicked and being updated.

Is there a best practice to do so? Or in other words, what's the best way to do it?

Is it using `.ajaxStart(function()` which only functions on a `$(document)`? Or should I be more specific in passing on which checkbox is being clicked?

Thanks